# Activation rectangle

Tags: visual-studio-2010, uml

Making UML sequence diagram in VS 2010RC I've observed that there is no activation rectangle in first object. Is this correct? Not according to my tutor and I have to quote him:
"Finally, you have no activation rectangle for the userInterface instance, so the initial message could never have been sent."

But I'm thinking that if guys from VS did that it must/should be correct.

Another thing he is picking me at is and I'm quoting him:
"In class diagram the generalisation arrow heads should be open triangles."
In my opinion there isn't strictly said that they must be open triangles especially when software lets you choose their form. Looking forward to hear your opinions.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Guys really no one will know that?

Comment: In school just go with what the tutor says, as this is what you'll be getting marked on. School != Real World. Don't over-think it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: With full respect for you but how does this answer to my question? I've asked if it is ok to not have activation rectangle in first object as this object always exists and you showing me some screengrab made not in VS.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer but I did not see your answer. Activation bar doesn't not exist anymore in UML2. It was very useful in UML 1.x

Answer (score 0):

In the first object you don't have to provide activation rectangle due to the fact that this object exists for all the time.